# Using a random number generator in MIPS?

Tags: random, mips, mars-simulator

So I was reading a few threads on this site and I found one on how to make one..
But I can't really find a link that explains more about how to code it..
My textbook for the course didn't provide any information about RNG at all so no help there.

The code was

```
li $a1, 4
li $v0, 42
add $a0, $a0, 1
```

is this correct for asking for a range between 1-3?
I tried outputting what random number it was but it gave me the same number constantly.

```
#sw $a0, 0($s0)
li $a1, 4
li $v0, 42
add $a0, $a0, 1
#syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, Checking
syscall

li $v0, 1
move $t0, $a0
syscall
```

I saw the `sw $a0, 0($s0)` but I'm not sure what that does  -- is it needed to output?  (I took it out because after I pushed a key to go to the RNG, it said the program crashed)
I keep getting the output of 268501267  which I'm not sure what that means 
edit:  now it started giving me 268500992 all the time

Can anyone help explain this a little more in depth?

Logically speaking -- I understand the where the 42 comes from and why I need to add +1  (This is so I won't get the value of 0)

From there, I have no clue on why the code won't output a number in the range I gave.

Comment: What syscall handler (kernel) are you using here? Also `syscall` instruction is commented...

Comment: Yeah I wasn't sure if syscall was needed in that certain spot as the page I got it from didn't use it.
It didn't seem to make a difference in the output if I used syscall or not so that's why I wasn't sure if it was needed in that particular spot of the code

I'm using MARS 4.4  Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: *"I'm using MARS 4.4 Is that what you're referring to?"* Yes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by [MARS documentation](https://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/Help/SyscallHelp.html) (in the GUI Help > Syscalls):

> random int 41 $a0 = i.d. of pseudorandom number generator (any int).
>   $a0 contains the next pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value
>   from this random number generator's sequence

So

```
li $v0, 41         ; Service 41, random int
li $a0, 0          ; Select random generator 0
syscall            ; Generate random int (returns in $a0)

li $v0, 1  ; Service 1, print int
syscall    ; Print previously generated random int
```

Works fine for me, every time a different number is printed.

You don't need to initialize or seed a random stream before using it, you can just use stream 0.

Comment: Don't use `xor` to zero MIPS registers; that's only useful on x86 which has variable-length instructions (and no zero register).  On MIPS, just copy from the zero register.  This avoids a false dependency (which you'd otherwise get on superscalar / out-of-order MIPS hardware because only x86 CPUs look for that xor-zeroing special case)