# Mars Mips creating a dice which shows 3 possible outcomes

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

im doing an assigment in school to make a program that shows three possible outcomes for a dice, used an array for this but i can only make it loop through the array and print all values rather than choosing a single when where all three outccomes have different probabilties.

```
.data

dragon: .asciiz "Dragon"
orc: .asciiz "Orc"
sword: .asciiz "sword"

dice: .word dragon, dragon, dragon, dragon, dragon, orc, orc, orc,
sword, sword, sword, sword

iterator: .word 0
size: .word 11

.text
main:

la $t0, dice
lw $t1, iterator
lw $t2, size     

beginLoop: bgt $t1, $t2, exitLoop     
sll $t3, $t1, 2     
addu $t3, $t3, $t0     
addi $t1, $t1, 1           
li $v0, 4
lw $a0, 0($t3)
syscall    
j beginLoop

exitLoop: li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Comment: How would you do it in C?

Comment: I'm not sure, to be honest, I'm still quite new to coding and I've not worked with c/python that much

Comment: Ok, so my point goes to where you're stuck and what you need help with: whether figuring out an algorithm to solve this problem (which is largely language independent), or, how to code up an algorithm you already understand in assembly.  It can be hard to develop an algorithm directly in assembly, so teasing these apart can be useful.  An algorithm is a series of steps in a strategy, that manipulates some information toward some purpose to get the answers we want.  We can use pseudo code, or C, or Java or C#.  Pseudo code is probably easiest but also least precise, and least verifiable.

Comment: https://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/Help/SyscallHelp.html shows that MARS does have some RNG system calls.  Use that to index your array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/Help/SyscallHelp.html shows that MARS does have some RNG system calls.  Use that to index your array.  [Using a random number generator in MIPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22900985/using-a-random-number-generator-in-mips)

You don't even have to map a random 32-bit integer to your range; MARS does that for you if you use syscall 42 instead of 41.  The syscall takes the ID # of a RNG as an input, but it seems you don't need to initialize it, just use `0`

```
.data
dragon: .asciiz "Dragon\n"
orc: .asciiz "Orc\n"
sword: .asciiz "Sword\n"

# this can't be line-wrapped, unless you use another .word directive
dice: .word dragon, dragon, dragon, dragon, dragon, orc, orc, orc, sword, sword, sword, sword
#.equ die_size, (. - dice)/4
#die_size = (. - dice)/4
.eqv die_size, 12        # 11 + 1
 # MARS built-in assembler is crap and can't calculate the size for us at assemble time.


.text
main:
    li $v0, 42             # Service 42, random int range
    li $a0, 0              # Select random generator 0
    li $a1, die_size      # upper bound of range (non-inclusive)
    syscall                # invoke the system call, returns in $a0
# $a0 is in the range [0..12), i.e. 0..11

    sll  $a0, $a0, 2        # scale by size of word, $a0 is a byte index into pointer array

    lw $a0, dice($a0)
    li $v0, 4            # print string
    syscall

    li  $v0, 17
    li  $a0, 0
    syscall       # exit(0) because MARS doesn't support returning from main!?!
    #    jr $ra
```

I have my MARS configured to put the data section in the low 16kiB of address space so I can use `dice($reg)` to index the array.  If you don't do that, you can use `addu` to do address math.

MARS's built-in assembler really sucks, and seems to force you to hard-code the size of the array as a literal number.  In a real assembler like GAS, you'd use `.equ die_size, (. - dice)/4 + 1` to calculate it at assemble time from the number of elements in the pointer array.